# Deploying java backend and Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, java, heroku, gradle, gulp

I have an app that I would like to deploy to Heruko. The `REST` API is built with `Dropwizard` and `Gradle` and the frontend is built with `javascript`. Is there a way to deploy the two together in the same file structure?

Comment: node.js is used for backend. how you are using it for frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Heroku's support for running [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) on an app. In short, you can run this:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:clear 
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/java
```

If your app has a `package.json` and a `pom.xml` this should pretty much just work. The only caveat you might run into is the `dependencies` versus `devDependencies` in the `package.json`. [The Node.js buildpack will not install `devDependencies` by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#configuring-npm), so you may need to run:

```
$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Here is an article that describes this setup for [Using Grunt with Java and Maven to Automate JavaScript Tasks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks), but it's basically the same for Gulp.

I don't understand your question about the symlinks.

**EDIT:**

Maybe the symlinks question implies that the code for the frontend and backend are not in the same repo? I recommend merging these, or using Git submodules. Or you can package the whole app (frontend assets and backend code) into an executable JAR file and deploy with [heroku-cli-deploy](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli-deploy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll certainly give that a try. Regarding my symlink question, my apps are in separate repos. On my machine the `REST` API runs on `localhost:8080.` The `gulpfile` runs the frontend on `localhost:8085` but is still able to fetch the API data. A friend suggested symlinks so that the two applications wouldn't have to run on different ports.